# Element with lower zindex and rotation applied ignores higher zindexes in Google Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, transform, z-index

I am trying to create a box which I can hover and additionally I need to rotate image behind the hover hitbox. But it seems that in Google Chrome specifically one part of image is in front of hitbox and the other one is behind despite the fact that hitbox is `z-index:2` and image is `z-index: 1`.

[Here is a demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/skmasq/3E25z/)

CSS:

```
.hitbox {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 2;
    background-color: rgba(255,50,0,0.3);
}
img.img-ele {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(15deg) rotateY(12deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateX(15deg) rotateY(12deg);
    -ms-transform: rotateX(15deg) rotateY(12deg);
    -o-transform: rotateX(15deg) rotateY(12deg);
    transform: rotateX(15deg) rotateY(12deg);
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="box">
        <div class="hitbox"></div>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/111x89/000" class="img-ele" />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="inside-container">Inside container</div>
<div class="inside-hitbox">Inside hitbox</div>
```

Is there a workaround or a different html markup I should try?

Comment: I don't understand what the issue is.

Comment: @j08691 If one part is over hitbox then `mouseleave` event is triggered immediately. FF and IE handles this correctly.

Comment: Visually the image is behind the hit box. Is the issue that the mouse events behave differently or what exactly is the problem?